# Explain what is wrong with the following proof that $1 = 0$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fake-proofs

By definition $\bigcup_{\omega\ \Omega}\{\omega\}=\{\omega : \exists \omega'\in \Omega\ \text{ with }\ \omega \in \{\omega'\}\}$.

\begin{align*}1 & =\mathbb{P}[\Omega] \tag{axiom 2}
\\ & =\mathbb{P}[\bigcup_{\omega\ \Omega}\{\omega\}] \tag{definition of union} 
\\ &=\sum_{\omega\ \Omega} \mathbb{P}[\{\omega\}] \tag{axiom 3} 
\\ &=\sum_{\omega\ \Omega} 0 \tag{assumption} 
\\ &=0.\end{align*}

I did not understand why in the definition $\omega \in \{\omega'\}$ and $\mathbb{P}[\{\omega\}]$ is $0$ by assumption. Is the proof wrong because it is using a wrong definition?

Edit: axioms refer to the three probability axioms

Comment: What are your axioms and assumptions here?  We need that context to answer

Comment: Do not confuse [sigma-additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-additive_set_function) with finite additivity.  Your "axiom 3" is incorrectly used.  Alternatively confusing countable additivity with uncountable additivity.

Comment: You haven't stated any assumptions. However, it is rather clear that your problem will arise from assuming $\Omega$ is countable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probability measures are only countably additive, so your "axiom 3" only applies if $\Omega$ is countable.

Your argument is therefore a proof (by contradiction) that if a probability space is countable, then the singleton events can't all have probability 0.